# if I clicked IBAction login button in login form,go to web view in ios

Tags: ios, button

If I pressed login action button

```
 - (IBAction)login button:(id)sender
```

I would like to go webview without using triggered segues.

Because I have two web views.If I pressed login button,I would like to go login webview, else I would like to go home webview. It depends on one button click.

I used delegate protocol and create two instance method and then,I would like to call method by using `[self method name].delegate` is okay but login button action didn't go to webview.

How can I do that?

**piece of code in viewcontroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)loginCompleted{

   NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.example.com/login";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [homeWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

 }

 -(void)homeCompleted{

  NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.example.com/home";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [homeWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
 }

  - (IBAction)loginEvent:(id)sender {
   if ([sender isEqual:loginbtn]) {
        [self loginCompleted];
        NSLog(@"Button pressed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Button pressed2");    }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have two web views"? Are you trying to say that your `WebView` can load two requests and you want to doing something based on the request when it is completed?

Comment: what is homeWebView, is  it add to self.view as subview, and if you press on login button sender always equal to login button.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your loginbtn? How you set it?

set it's tag

```
loginbtn.tag = 1
```

In loginEvent compare the tag like this

```
if (sender.tag == 1) {
    [self loginCompleted];
    NSLog(@"Button pressed");
} else {

    NSLog(@"Button pressed2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select and deselect your button depending on what action you want to trigger: `loginbtn.isSelected=true`. And then:

```
- (IBAction)loginEvent:(id)sender {
   if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [self loginCompleted];
        NSLog(@"Button pressed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Button pressed2");    
    }
 }
```

(I write in Swift so it might be written a bit differently)

Answer (score 0):

What you say 'If I pressed login button,I would like to go login web view,else I would like to go home web view.It depends on one button click.' causes me confused.What are the 'else cases' ?

I guest you are hoping to load the home page first,if the user press login button,it goes to the login page.

If it's true,you should add `requestObj` to the view controller's property,cancel the request if needed when the user press login button.

You say you have two webViews,but you load login request to the `homeWebView` see `loginCompleted` method